# Why aren't there any gold tag badge(s)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As title says, why aren't there any gold tag badges in this site? I've seen gold tag badge on other SE family sites.

[image]

Also in meta site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Gold Tag Badge requires:

> You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

Well, that is *very* hard. Nobody has achieved that yet on Ask Ubuntu. Other sites like Stack Overflow have more common tags that trigger this as well as a much higher upvote rate.

More badges aren't achieved by anyone here. For example [`Legendary`](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/43/legendary) - no one has it yet.

Comment: Not to mention more questions on [so].

Comment: 'Other sites like Stack Overflow have more common tags ...' AU have common tags too...

Comment: We need to work on I upvote rate too..

Comment: As AskUbuntu evolved into a site used for user support there are many questions with rather narrow scope (and accordingly small audience). Many of them loose their importance after a (relatively) short time. So the "bubble up through upvotes" process doesn't even start on many answers.

Comment: What I mean with 'common tags' is that for example on SO you have programming languages tags like `c#`, `c++`, etc. Such popular tags are used so much more relatively to an average tag on Ubuntu. Top-10 tag on SO is asked avg 200 times per day, on AU this is about 15. Then the upvote rate should be multiplied on that number. This makes the amount of votes per tag *a lot* different on SO compared to AU.

Comment: Note for future historians: on May 22nd 2018, the total count of gold tag badges awarded on Ask Ubuntu was 22